# How to use a p:dataTable with p:columnGroup headers using p:columns

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-datatable

My current code is:

```html
<p:dataTable value="#{bean.studentList}" var="student">

    <p:columns var="column" value="#{bean.columnList}"
        rowspan="#{column.rowSpan}" colspan="#{column.colSpan}">

            <f:facet name="header">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{column.columnName}" />
            </f:facet>

    </p:columns>

</p:dataTable>
```

columnList is a List of Column and it contains

```
[Column [columnName=SId, rowSpan=3, colSpan=1], Column [columnName=SName, rowSpan=3, colSpan=1], Column [columnName=SBranch, rowSpan=3, colSpan=1], Column [columnName=Sem, rowSpan=1, colSpan=4], Column [columnName=Sem1, rowSpan=1, colSpan=2], Column [columnName=Sem2, rowSpan=1, colSpan=2], Column [columnName=Sub1, rowSpan=1, colSpan=1], Column [columnName=Sub2, rowSpan=1, colSpan=1], Column [columnName=Sub1, rowSpan=1, colSpan=1], Column [columnName=Sub2, rowSpan=1, colSpan=1]]
```

The Output I expect:
[image]

The output I got:
[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: Use `p:columnGroup`. https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/group.xhtml

Comment: @JasperdeVries I'm not sure where to use `p:columnGroup` to make this work. I have used it for static DataTable, but not for Dynamic.

Comment: @JasperdeVries In the first image I have posted, I have referred the same link as you have said. It works fine for static columns. But my question is how do I make it work for dynamic columns

Comment: @JasperdeVries Thank you. I found this [closed GitHub issue](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1886) . But I'm still facing issue in getting the expected output. Can you help me out on this one?

Comment: @JasperdeVries He want's to use both row/colspan[achieved using columnGroup] and dynamic columns in his TreeTable. He says It's working fine with DataTable

Comment: Neither your question or the GitHub issue speaks of a specific version of PrimeFaces. Please create a [mcve]. And try with PF8.0RC3.